# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable, BeautifulSoup webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Help please. I'm having TypeError below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_first_webscrape.py", line 22, in <module>
    brand_name = brand[0].img["title"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Here's my code:

```
import bs4

from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/global/ph-en/Laptops-Notebooks/SubCategory/ID-32?Tid=702226'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})
container = containers[0]

for container in containers:
    brand = container.findAll("div", {"class":"item-branding"})
    brand_name = brand[0].img["title"]

    title = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-title"})
    title_name = title[0].text

    price = container.findAll("li", {"class":"price-current"})
    price_current = price[0].strong.text

    print("brand_name: " + brand_name)
    print("title_name: " + title_name)
    print("price_current: " + price_current)
```

================================================

I think the error comes from brand_name returning None but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `brand` is most likely None, likely because the search didn't return any results. Did you read the documentation for that method?

Comment: You cuold either use a condition or catch the exception.

Comment: i ran your full code and did not get any error. Why you occur this may website sent you data that you do not want. such as 404page 403page

Answer (score 0):

your code work fine but newegg has anti bot it might be your IP is blocked, change your IP or use proxy.

try print `page_html` you will see

> Robot?
>
> That's not you, right?